# Swing java. Inheritance - frames with the same elements

Tags: java, swing

I have MainFrame which contains a lot of buttons, filled text areas and by clicking a button a want to go to other frame (NewFrame1) which will have the same look, elements etc. as MainFrame. Do I need to copy all stuff or is there other way to do that?

Comment: Create a base class, probably which extends from `JPanel` which contains the basic UI elements you want to use.  Show as many instances of this on as many containers as you want

Comment: `Component` and its subclasses (ie everything in AWT and Swing) can only have 1 parent. So if you want to have the same look, you need to create a copy of everything

Comment: By "copy" do you mean the data or the code?

Comment: Can't you just create two instances of the same class?

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)